# Return the running total of a specific item # from a non-static list of multiple item #'s

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a simplified logistics spreadsheet that has a static tab of items (titled 'Items available') and their available quantities that, for each item, displays the running total of that item in inventory by referencing another tab ('Released & added') of items and their continually added & subtracted quantities.

The 'Released & added' tab will be a dynamic one and will use positive integers when a part quantity is being added and negative integers when they are being reduced. A formula that counts the number of rows in the dynamic tab in order to determine the table set first would be preferable, but for my own purposes, setting lookup range to a static quantity such as 2000 would suffice.

I have tried using various formulas that utilize INDEX and MATCH, however, I cannot seem to find a solution that properly hashes the table array in the released & added tab and it looks to me as if the AGGREGATE function may be required to do so.

Sheet1:

```
| Part Code | Available quantity |
|-----------|--------------------|
| ABC123    | Should be 35       |
| XYZ321    | Should be 21       |
| EFG456    | Should be 25       |
```

Sheet2:

```
| Part Code | Released / Added |
|-----------|------------------|
| ABC123    | 55               |
| XYZ321    | 28               |
| ABC123    | -12              |
| EFG456    | 35               |
| EFG456    | -10              |
| XYZ321    | -7               |
| ABC123    | -8               |
```

Comment: Can you provide some markdown sample data? Using [this](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) tool for example. Please let us know expected result as well. Right now it's just a lot of text and hard to picture what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Right, you seem to benefit from using `SUMIF()`

[image]

The formula used in B2 translates to:

```
=SUMIF(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$8,Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!$B$2:$B$8)
```

Comment: Thanks JvdV - I seem to have drastically over complicated as I always do.

Comment: Also, I tried re-formatting but you were quicker to do so. Thanks Again!

Comment: @BrianHoulihan, glad it has been helpfull :)